# How can I see the price of an app I already purchased on the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I would like to find out the price of an app that I have already purchased, so that I can suggest it to a friend. When I look at the app listing, it doesn't give the price if I already have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user acejavelin stated either incognito or logout of google account. Which is what I suspected.

Answer (score 4):

You can search it on the website of Google Play Store

Comment: But you would have to do it in an incognito/private browsing tab... or log out of your Google account in that browser, otherwise it just says "Installed" or "Purchased" and does not list the price. There is no way to do with within the Play Store app when you have your Google account active in the app.

Answer (score 1):

In the play store app swipe form the left then go to Account and tap on ORDER History.

Comment: If the price of the app changed since the time user bought it, this solution would show an obsolete price. I have bought many apps at 100% discount (during an offer period), so this solution is not reliable.